# Convert a Stock Return Dataframe to MultiIndex Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe with Date as Index and 35 Columns. The Columns name are the name of the Stock. The values represent the Stock Returns.

I want to convert this dataframe to MultiIndex dataframe with Date as 1st level index, and stock name as 2nd level index, and the only column showing the stock return value.

I have already tried this but I didn't get the dataframe I was expecting.

```
df.set_axis(df.columns.str.split(' ', 1, expand=True), 1, 0).stack(0)
```

I'm expecting something like this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFSy4.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df.stack().rename('value_col').to_frame()
```

where `df` is your dataframe with 'Date' as index.

Comment: wow. That is so cool. Worked like a charm. Thank You very much. The name of the second index is still blank. How I can name the second level index as "Stock"?

Comment: Hi @Dan! You can do it by calling `.rename_axis(index={None:'sec_level'})` before `.to_frame()`. Best!